# RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota

Tags: openai-api, rate-limiting

I tried openai api but showing this error

Retrying langchain.llms.openai.completion_with_retry.._completion_with_retry in 4.0 seconds as it raised RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details..
Retrying langchain.llms.openai.completion_with_retry.._completion_with_retry in 4.0 seconds as it raised RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details..
Retrying langchain.llms.openai.completion_with_retry.._completion_with_retry in 4.0 seconds as it raised RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details..
Retrying langchain.llms.openai.completion_with_retry.._completion_with_retry in 8.0 seconds as it raised RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details..
Retrying langchain.llms.openai.completion_with_retry.._completion_with_retry in 10.0 seconds as it raised RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details

RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.

I was not able get ouput even once.

[I was trying for first time langchain but it shows at first atempt,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qybyq.png)

Comment: What does your open ai account dashboard say? More often than not the user's key has been compromised by sketchy packages from around the internet.